# How to type custom runtime features?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I'm working on TypeScript typings for a custom JavaScript environment. It exposes some functions in the global scope.

```js
const file = open('file.csv')
```

The standard pattern for declaration files seems to document an imported module or a script loaded with an HTML tag. But these functions are available before anything has been imported.

**Is there a good way to type features available without an import?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as declaration files are concerned, there's no difference between features available through an HTML tag or from the Javascript environment itself: In either case the TypeScript compiler needs to understand declarations that it does not generate itself, that may be loaded from an external source.

With that in mind, you can define the types for your environment using normal [declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html). You can use [the declare keyword](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2013/07/22/quick-tip-typescript-declare-keyword/) and [ambient namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#ambient-namespaces) to declare variables, methods, and dictionaries available to your scripts.

```
declare function open(filename: string): YourFile;
```

When compiling, make sure the declaration file is one of the inputs to `tsc`, by configuring it to be in `tsconfig.json` or by listing it as a `<reference>` using [triple-slash directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html).